# PKCS11 Mechanisms difference + JAVA

Tags: java, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, pkcs#11

I'm implementing functions with PKCS11 mechanisms - CKM_RSA_PKCS and CKM_RSA_X_509. I know that both are implemented in Botan C++ library, but I have to find equivalents in Java. Second problem is what's the difference between both of them?

Answer (score 4):

[`CKM_RSA_PKCS`](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__12__1__6__PKCS____1__V1__5__RSA.html) refers to the PKCS#1 v1.5 standard (see [RFC3447](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt)) for RSA encryption and digital signatures. In Java JCE, it is typically the default choice for RSA.

- For digital signatures, pass *"MD5WithRSA"*, *"SHA1WithRSA"*, etc to `Signature.getInstance()`
- For encryption, pass *"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"* to `Cipher.getInstance()`.

[`CKM_RSA_X_509`](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__12__1__12__X__509____RSA.html) refers to the textbook (or raw) RSA algorithm, that is, the one where no padding is defined. In this case, you can simply pass *"RSA/None/NoPadding"* to `Cipher.getInstance()`. Signature can be done with decryption, wheres verification can be done with encryption (followed by comparison).

I would avoid implementing and using raw RSA though, unless you have specific use cases in mind. PKCS#1v 1.5 signatures are more secure. For enciphering though, I wouldn't actually recommend to use either of them, because they are both unsecure. It's better to rely only on PKCS#1 OAEP ([`CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP`](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__12__1__8__PKCS____1__RSA__OAEP.html)); for that, you pass *"RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"* to `Cipher.getInstance()`.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for answer. Of course it's working, but today I recognize that I need to add padding before making encryption operations, means plain text with added padding. I tried to google it, but all results that I found was about all encryption operation.

Comment: Ok, Finally I found it! If it would be helpful for someone - I found java class - RSAPadding class which could be used to generate padded text from plain. The only problem I found is that method pad(byte[]) generates padded text with leading 0 which in my case should be trimmed.